# Limit results on a ldap requestion with zend_ldap

Tags: pagination, ldap, limit, zend-framework

I'm actually working with Zend Framework and I would like to get informations from a ldap directory. For that, I use this code :

```
$options = array('host' => '...', 'port' => '...', ...);

$ldap = new Zend_Ldap($options);

$query = '(username=' . $_GET['search'] . ')';

$attributes = array('id', 'username', ...);

$searchResults = $ldap->search($query, $ldap->getBaseDn(), Zend_Ldap::SEARCH_SCOPE_SUB, $attributes);

$ldap->disconnect();
```

There is may be many results so I would like to realize a pagination by limiting the number of results. I searched in the paramters of the search() function of Zend_Ldap which have a sort parameter but nothing to give an interval.

Do you have a solution to limit the number of results (as in sql with limit 0, 200 for example) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A client-requested size limit can be used to limit the number of entries the directory server will return. The client-requested size limit cannot override any server-imposed size limit, however. The same applies to the time limit. All searches should include a non-zero size limit and time limit. Failure to include size limit and time limit is very bad form. See ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/605075ef-e73b-40c6-9a4e-5f8b453cf42b/860bc618b3b1af121730469e7f3325ee) and ["LDAP: Search Practices"](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/3ec0447f-6a21-4343-9d72-09b1b0e779ec/a3b70abbdad6efdf6d92c8c20bfa76a3) for more information.

"Paging" is accomplished using the simple paged results control extension. described in my blog entry: ["LDAP: Simple Paged Results"](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/5d023647-593f-4dfc-ae45-04e25654a49c/7f591ae32905be9119bdc4b3a0a13863).

Alternatively, a search result listener, should your API support it, could be used to handle results as they arrive which would reduce memory requirements of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current releases of PHP don't support the ldap pagination functions out of the box - see http://sgehrig.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/reading-paged-ldap-results-with-php-is-a-show-stopper/

If you have control of your server environment, there's a patch you can install with PHP 5.3.2 (and possibly others) that will allow you to do this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42060.

.... or you can wait until 5.4.0 is released for production, which should be in the next few weeks, and which include this feature.

ldap_control_paged_results() and ldap_control_paged_results_response() are the functions you'll want to use if you're going with the patch. I think they have been renamed to the singular ldap_control_paged_result() and ldap_control_paged_result_response() in 5.4.

Good luck!